# How to create database in MVC 5 when you already have models and context?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-5

I have context db class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication.Models {
    public class PeopleContextDb : DbContext {

        public PeopleContextDb() : base("PeopleContextDb") { }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

I have this class( do I have right namespace):

```
using MvcApplication.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication.App_Start {
    public class PeopleInitilizer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PeopleContextDb> {
        protected override void Seed(PeopleContextDb context) {
            var people = new List<Person> { 
             new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now, Pesel = "312312312", Notes = "Annoying"},
             new Person{FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now, Pesel = "548555672", Notes = "Less Annoying"}
            };

            people.ForEach(person => context.People.Add(person));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

but still my project has no database in it how to generate one?

I added connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication-20140710053828.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication-20140710053828;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PeopleContextDb"    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Code First Migrations** technique using Entity Framework to create and update your database files. This method of keeping the database in sync with the data model works well until you deploy the application to production.

There are three steps involve with this process that you have already done the first one:

1. Building an Initial Model & Database
2. Enabling Migrations
3. Generating & Running Migrations

There are two good articles about the ways of Code First Migration that you can find out from the links below:

[Code First Migrations and Deployment with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

[Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621#model)